# How to run IISExpress command on ASP.NET 4.6.2 in project.json

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I need to test my .NET Core/.NET 4.6.2 library on both ASP.NET 4 and ASP.NET 5. I have ASP.NET 5/MVC6 working with dnx and the ASP.NET 4/MVC 5 project will build.

I cannot get the ASP.NET 4 and MVC 5 website running because I cannot find the command to put into project.json to kick of IIExpress when I press F5 in Visual Studio.

I have two Visual Studio 2015 solutions with project.json/.xproj libraries. The working ASP.NET 5/MVC 6 project.json is:

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0-*",
  "compilationOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": true
  },

  "commands": {
    "web": "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel"
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "dnxcore5": {
      "dependencies": {
        "Microsoft.AspNet.IISPlatformHandler": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
        "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc": "6.0.0-rc1-final",
        "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
        "Microsoft.AspNet.StaticFiles": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
        "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileProviderExtensions": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
        "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
        "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
        "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
        "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
        "NJsonApiCore": "1.0.0-*",
        "NJsonApiCore.Web.MVC6": "1.0.0-*"
      }
    }
  },

  "exclude": [
    "wwwroot",
    "node_modules"
  ],
  "publishExclude": [
    "**.user",
    "**.vspscc"
  ]
}
```

The ASP.NET 4/MVC5 project.json is:

```
{
"version": "1.0.0-*",
  "description": "NJsonApiCore Web MVC5 Class Library",
  "authors": [ "Rob" ],
  "tags": [ "" ],
  "projectUrl": "",
  "licenseUrl": "",
  "frameworks": {
    "net46": {
      "dependencies": {
        "Microsoft.Owin": "3.0.1",
        "Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi": "5.2.3",
        "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc": "5.2.3"
      },
      "frameworkAssemblies": {
        "System.Web": "4.0.0.0"
      }
    }
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "NJsonApiCore": "1.0.0-*",
    "NJsonApiCore.Web.MVC5": "1.0.0-*"
  }
}
```

## Edit - Trying to run via IIS Express

In the MVC5 project json, I have tried adding the IISExpress command line option:

```
"commands": {
    "iisexpress": "c:\\\\Program Files (x86)\\\\IIS Express\\\\iisexpress /path:C:\\Projects\\NJsonApiCore\\src\\NJsonApiCore.Web.MVC5.HelloWorld\\bin /port:12345"
  },
```

Although the application starts, I get the error:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: The current runtime target framework is not compatible with 'NJsonApiCore.Web.MVC5.HelloWorld'.
Current runtime target framework: 'DNX,Version=v4.5.1 (dnx451)'
 Version:      1.0.0-rc1-16231
 Type:         Clr
 Architecture: x86
 OS Name:      Windows
 OS Version:   10.0
 Runtime Id:   win10-x86

  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/533jo.png
```

Which shows that it is trying to run my ASP.NET 4/MVC 5 application in dnx, which I know won't work. My global.json looks like:

```
{
  "projects": [ "src/NJsonApiCore", "src/NJsonApiCore.Web.MVC6", "src/NJsonApiCore.Web.MVC6.HelloWorld", "test" ],
  "sdk": {
    "version": "1.0.0-rc1-update1"
  }
}
```

Which shows that only the MVC6 sister projects are referenced. You can see the full tree here: https://github.com/brainwipe/NJsonApiCore/tree/feature/net462withxproj

I have also tried moving the MVC5 solution out of the base directory but I received the same error.

Is it possible to run a ASP.NET 4/MVC5 using project.json and xproj?

Comment: Any luck on this? I'm running into a similar issue attempting to get Microsoft.Aspnet.Mvc 1.0.0 running using IIS Express. I'm upgrading from DNX to RTM 1.0 and receiving 502.3 errors from IIS

Comment: Hi @letsgetsilly, the answer I received was that you cannot run ASP.NET/MVC5 with project.json and xproj and soon (December 2016) the .json and .xproj formats will be removed so there won't be any development on it. The work around was to have two project files for each assembly. I'll add that as an answer.

Comment: Actually, having read your comment again, I think you misunderstand my original question, I wasn't using Core, I was using .NET 4 and .NET Core together.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was: Is it **NOT** possible to run a ASP.NET 4/MVC5 using project.json and xproj.

### The Work Around

The work around was to have two solutions (one .NET 4, one .NET Core) and then two project files for each assembly (csproj for .NET 4 and xproj for .NET Core). The .NET 4 solution would point at the csproj for each assembly and the .NET Core solution would point at the .xproj.

Additionally, you needed to add another json for the .csproj ([Github Issue explanation](https://github.com/Microsoft/msbuild/issues/394)). Which is of the format `NameOfYourProject.project.json` and in there add your .NET dependencies. For example:

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0-*",
  "description": "NJsonApiCore Class Library",
  "authors": [ "Rob" ],
  "tags": [ "" ],
  "projectUrl": "",
  "licenseUrl": "",
  "runtimes": { "win": { } },
  "frameworks": {
    "net452": {
      "dependencies": {
        "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc": "5.2.3",
        "Humanizer.Core": "2.0.1",
        "Newtonsoft.Json": "8.0.2"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

### Project.json and Xproj are obsolete

Just before .NET Core was released, [Microsoft announced](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2016/05/23/changes-to-project-json/) that project.json and xproj would be **deprecated**. Project.json was created in a time when the .NET platform was smaller (without Xamarin) and to move all the platforms to project.json was not worth the effort. Instead they say they would 'fix' the problems with csproj. At time of writing (July 2016), this has not yet happened but is slated for the end of 2016.

> We had two choices. One was to move all .NET projects to use project.json. This would require us doing tooling work that touches all of the project types in Visual Studio, Xamarin and our partners like Unity. We would have to expand project.json to support all the build scenarios required by each of these project types and provide a migration story. Another choice was to build bridges so an .xproj project can reference a .csproj project and a .csproj project can reference an .xproj project in Visual Studio and Xamarin Studio. The bridge has challenges as well, for example when a customer creates a project they would now have to choose an .xproj or a .csproj, which just adds more choices and complexity.
>
> After looking at our choices, it was apparent that it would be easier to move .NET Core projects to .csproj/MSBuild so all .NET projects use the same tooling and build system.
>
> [Quote Reference](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2016/05/23/changes-to-project-json/)

Any fix you put in now will need to be refactored when this change happens.

Answer (score 0):

[Source link to see more commands](http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/using-iis-express/running-iis-express-from-the-command-line)

**open command prompt**
**go to your IIS Express directory** (example: cd \Program Files\IIS Express)
`iisexpress /?` command to check usage string of your iis express

Then there are different commands to open your website in iis express like
 `iisexpress /site:WebSite1`

for more commands visit link above
Hope it helps

Comment: Please re-read the question fully. I am talking about running commands from within Visual Studio 2015 using the commands json entry. I have tried using the IISCommand Line but received errors.

Comment: If you want to launch your project from inside visual studio you canright click on the web project, chose properties and then navigated to the "web" tab than select IIS Express and select port to launch your project on iis server
http://i.stack.imgur.com/zFyX6.png

Comment: That dialog only exists if you are using .csproj. I am using the project.json/xproj format so I do not have that dialog box.